# SQL - Finding percentage population between 0 and population average

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find the percentage of population for each grouped row between 0 and the average of that group. For example, in the below query, say I have a row where num_problems is 100 and average is 70. There are 58 values in the population (for that row) which have values below 70. I want to extract the value (58) as a part of the result tupule.

```
select
    tm.subject_name,
    tm.topic_name,
    pm.problem_type,
    count( pa.id ) as num_problems,
    avg( pa.duration ) as average ,
    stddev( pa.duration )
from
    problem_attempt pa,
    problem_master pm,
    topic_master tm
where
    pa.problem_id = pm.id and
    pm.topic_id = tm.id and
    pa.outcome = 'Solved' and
    pa.duration > 10 and 
    pa.duration < 1000 and
    pm.problem_type = 'SCA'
group by
    tm.subject_name,
    tm.topic_name,
    pm.problem_type ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

You need to aggregate twice or use a window function.

I would recommend:

```
select subject_name, topic_name, problem_type,
       count(*) as num_problems,
       average ,
       stddev( pa.duration ),
       sum(case when pa_duration < average then 1 else 0 end) as num_less_than_average
from (select tm.subject_name, tm.topic_name, pm.problem_type,
             avg( pa.duration ) over (partition by tm.subject_name, tm.topic_name, pm.problem_type) as average
      from problem_attempt pa join
           problem_master pm
           on pa.problem_id = pm.id
           topic_master tm
           on pm.topic_id = tm.id
      where pa.outcome = 'Solved' and
            pa.duration > 10 and 
            pa.duration < 1000 and
            pm.problem_type = 'SCA'
     ) x
group by subject_name, topic_name, problem_type, average ;
```